# Can't get counter track double values python

Tags: python, csv

So I'm trying to count the number of occurences for each item of my first column csv file. But the result is not correct : I have an output like this : OrderedDict([('3178040678842', 1), ('4005808283804', 1), ('3337872414527', 1), 
.. while each number appears like 2 or 3 times in the csv file.

Here is the code :

```
import csv
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

#the purpose of this small script is checking if values are double in EAN 
list result

eans_to_count = set()
with open("example.csv", "r") as new_data:
reader = csv.reader(new_data, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    if row:
        ean = row[0]
        eans_to_count.add(ean)

x = Counter(eans_to_count)
y = OrderedDict(x.most_common())
print(y)
```

do you know where i am wrong ? Because I'm sure that the result is uncorrect

Comment: You're storing the `ean` values in a `set` so there will always be only 1 of each value in there. Try `eans_to_count` = list()

Comment: Works better now ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set` is discarding duplicate values before you count them.  The normal way to use a `Counter` is to add *directly* to it:

```
eans_to_count = Counter()
with open("example.csv", "r") as new_data:
    reader = csv.reader(new_data, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            ean = row[0]
            eans_to_count[ean] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the good practice :) I also would have a question. For now I just check if EAN is several times into the list. The output is like : 
876543 : 4, 987668 : 3, etc.
But instead of the "4", or "3", if I want to get the info linked to each EAN
So that : "876543: [apple, banana, strawberry, pineapple]
Would it be possible ?

Comment: @Araxide: You use `dict.setdefault(...,[]).append` or `collections.defaultdict(list)[...].append` for that; it’s a very common pattern.